# Why is this JSX code reported as unreachable in the return statement?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

In my react native function component I have the following function:

```
const renderStatus = () => {
    if (status == Status.PENDING) {
        return
        (
            <Text>{Texts.statusPending}</Text>
        )
    }
    if (status == Status.DONE) {
        return
        (
            <Text>{Texts.statusDone}</Text>
        )
    }
    if (status == Status.UPLOADING) {
        return
        (
            <>
                <Text>{Texts.statusUploading}</Text>
                <Loader style={{ margin: 8 }} />
            </>
        )
    }
    if (status == Status.FAILED) {
        return
        (
            <>
                <Text>{Texts.statusFailed}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: 'Crimson' }}>{model.error}</Text>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

For each of the `return` VSCode reports that JSX inside brackets is not reachable,
and the function actually behaves like that, returns `undefined`.

[image: VSCode issue]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bring the "(" next to return instead of the next line.

Comment: Huh, that was it... Thank you very much! What a nonsense syntax.
Someone should really write article named 'Beware of the open bracket location when using JSX'.

Comment: check out my answer, maybe it will help you out for future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put brackets after return like:

```
 return( <Text>{Texts.statusPending}</Text> )
```

because it stops on return and don't go to the next line. For future use code formatters so it will automatically format your code every time you save the file. Most popular is [prettier](https://prettier.io/). So you will not have problems like that because it will format your code in good way right after you click CTRL+S